# JNI memory leak from byte array

Tags: java, c++, memory-leaks, java-native-interface

I have a java program that calls a native function many times over. My problem is that this function has a memory leak and everything that I do to get rid of it cause a memory dump. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

This is my code

```
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_class_method_getInput
(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    if (inputIsAvailable)
    {

    int size = getBufferCurrentIndex();
    size -= getBufferReadIndex();
    size *= 2;

    char *finalSendArray = new char[size];

    getCommand(finalSendArray);

    jbyteArray byteArray = env->NewByteArray(size / 2);
    env->SetByteArrayRegion(byteArray, 0, size / 2, (jbyte*) finalSendArray);

    while(methodID == 0)
    {
        jclass cls = env->GetObjectClass(obj);
        methodID = env->GetMethodID(cls, "setCommand", "([B)V" );
    }

    env->CallVoidMethod(obj, methodID, byteArray);

    //env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(byteArray, (jbyte*) finalSendArray, JNI_ABORT);
```

My problem is that the above ^ code causes a memory dump if it is uncommented, if it is not uncommented my program runs out of memory in minutes

```
    env->DeleteLocalRef(byteArray);
    delete[] finalSendArray;
    }
}
```

any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Release the `byteArray` first, then delete the underlying memory?

Comment: Did my response solve your issue? Mark it as correct if it did. Why are you doing this all in C? What does getCommand do? Could it be done in java? jni is expensive.

Comment: @JustinDanielson hey sorry it took so long for a reply, I still have a leak somewhere. I'm not sure where. I'm using c++ because I am just reusing code that was already built. It could be re-written in Java but I would prefer just keeping it in it's current implementation.

Comment: @KerrekSB I wish that had worked... but it did not unfortunately.

Comment: Sorry to hear. I don't really know; the only advice I could give is to read the JNI spec carefully and make sure you understand all the different lifetimes and dependencies.

Comment: Did you solve the problem? What was causing it? I'm curious because I've been working with some JNI related stuff and run into strange things pretty often.

Comment: unfortunately I did not solve the problem / I could not find the problem. I ended up re-writing it in Java. Sorry, wish I had found it, but best of luck and thanks for your help!

Comment: That's not good Im finding the same problem here.

Answer (score 4):

ReleaseByteArrayElements will also free the memory if you use the JNI_ABORT param. So when you're doing the delete and release later on, one of those pointers is pointing to uninitialized memory which is causing the dump.

One of these will work, I fairly certain it is the first one that works.

```
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(byteArray, (jbyte*) finalSendArray, JNI_ABORT);
delete[] finalSendArray;
```

Try this if the first fails.

```
env->ReleaseByteArrayElements(byteArray, (jbyte*) finalSendArray, JNI_ABORT);
env->DeleteLocalRef(byteArray);
```

Put a print statement after the ReleaseByteArrayElements, you will see that your program is executing beyond that command and crashing on the Release/Delete[]

[Search for "Table 4-10 Primitive Array Release Modes"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jni/spec/functions.html)

Comment: the first one causes `code` *** glibc detected *** /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/bin/java: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007fb8a4001030 *** `code` the second one I still have a memory leak. I'm going to make sure that the memory leak is actually there

Comment: It could be in getCommand. Is it no longer crashing now in the same place?

Comment: The log files point to the function SetByteArrayRegion and it throws the error bad_alloc

Comment: Could either of your allocations be failing?(returning null). How much memory do you have allocated to the JVM? Check if either of those pointers are NULL before calling setByteArrayRegion. If they are, print something out, write to the log, or throw an exception. Is bad_alloc throwing on the first JNI call? or after a bunch?(mem leak)

Comment: It could be that you're running out of heap memory. Check out this to increase it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565388/increase-heap-size-in-java